# How to receive a dynamic variable from a website (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, dynamic, shoutcast

I'm not exactly sure how to state this but here's the basic idea of what I'm trying to do:

I'm making a radio player application in Android Java. The function I'm looking at including is a dynamic TextView that get's the title of the song that's currently playing from either the website or ShoutCast.

My thoughts as they stand now is that my XML can stay as it is (a "content_wrap"-ed @string value). I just have no idea if there's a way to change that XML from Java and how to get the HTML (I'm not even sure if I need to use HTML) from the website.

Thank you in advance. You are all great people for even reading this :)

Comment: One way to do it is simply to make a webservice that finds the song title, song artist, etc. and sends those out to you via your webservice url (example: http://www.website.com/services/nowplaying.ashx) - when you call this page, you then output those properties (JSON would be a good output format). This webservice should then be called in your android app away from the ui thread so it doesn't block, then you check for a 200 reply and show the received answer - and maybe even fill an object with the received properties to keep it tidy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question (regarding what I was looking for). I believe what I was starting with was javascript (something like a webplayer that constantly updated, so the title wasn't actually in the code nor the redirection).

What I did was from a permanent list (a played list in my case) and connect to that URL with a URLconnection (java.net.URL & java.net.URLConnection) then use a BufferedReader (java.io.BufferedReader). This part can probably be optomized more using the BufferedReader's mark and restart methods, but for this one I just kept circling though until I found a permanent mark then trimmed it till I found what I needed.

e.g.

```
while (!br.contains("PERMANANT MARK BEFORE MY DESIRED INFO"))
      br.readLine(); //Which advances the line
String s = br.readLine(); //Repeat this till you get your info into s
//Trim functions (I used the </td> to my advantage)
s = s.split("THING NEXT TO INFO")[0[;
display.setText(s);
```

Thank you to everyone who read this. Good luck on your endeavors!